# Exponential distribution - estimate population proportion

Tags: exponential-distribution

I have the following question:

How do you estimate the population proportion of bulbs that survive at least 7 months without any assumption about the lifetime distribution? (with a mean of $0.4257$ years)

What does this exactly mean and how do I find the population proportion? Do I simply conduct a 1-sample Z-test? Or do I use a point estimator?

Comment: You don't use a $z$-test; it's an exponential distribution.  (I'm assuming it's exponential because it's in your title and your tag, but I notice that it's not in the question.  Can you give more context behind the question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value of an exponential distribution completely determines that distribution.  Without it, it is impossible to say what proportion of light bulbs survive $7$ months.

---

If we know that the mean is $0.4257$ years, then the distribution must have the CDF

$$
F(t) = 1-e^{-\frac{t}{0.4257}}
$$

$F(t)$ is the probability that the event of interest (in this case, the bulb failing) happens before time $t$, so if you plug in a $t$ of $7$ months ($\doteq 0.5833$ years), you should obtain the probability that a bulb fails within $7$ months.  Subtracting that from $1$ gives you the probability that it survives $7$ months.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the mean is 0.4257 (in years)

Comment: @NAA: OK, that helps.